# Is this expected behavior from the file() function?

Tags: php, file, newline

In a php 7.0.3 environment I have a file containing only a single newline character("\n") and I do the following:

```
var_dump(file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
```

the output is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Which is wrong, as the file effectively consists of two empty lines.

Is this expected from the file function to just ignore the last line if its empty?
Any reliable workarounds that behave just like the file function but that don't ignore the last line if empty?

Comment: File consists of one empty line and one new line symbol. So everything is fine.

Comment: Yes, it is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @u_mulder so if a file is empty it returns one empty line, and if there is a single newline... there is still one empty line? I don't understand how is this expected, should return two empty lines.

Comment: @user2464424 if the file is empty it return **0** empty lines.

Comment: @fusion3k ok so it returns an empty array for empty file. but still, with a single newline notepad++ effectively tells me that there are two lines. I still can't comprehend how php fails at returning two as i would expect.

Comment: php refer to POSIX line definition: “A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character”. In fact, in POSIX we can consider a file without an ending newline as a _not well formed_ file.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) summarizes it pretty good:

> Two ways to view newlines, both of which are self-consistent, are that
>   newlines separate lines or that they terminate lines. If a newline is
>   considered a separator, there will be no newline after the last line
>   of a file.

You might want to use `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` instead; it [returns the empty array you expect](https://3v4l.org/oKgh6)